# Find people with at least 2 purchases of the same product in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have this data for example :

```
ProductName     ServiceDate   Name   StockId   Fee

LG                1/10/2011    John   1         0 
Sony              2/20/2011    Mike   2         0 
LG                1/11/2011    John   1         0
Samsung           2/21/2011    Steve  3         0 
Toshiba           3/2/2011     Kelly  4         0 
LG                5/6/2011     Sean   1         0
```

now imagine there are millions of records. How do I find the people who bought 2 or more products in the same month with the same stockid?

Comment: Can we assume the same month of the same year?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a `GROUP BY` statement. 
The only wrinkle is you have to use `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions to convert your `date` to a usable format to group on.

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    Products
GROUP BY
        MONTH(ServiceDate)
        , YEAR(ServiceDate)
        , StockID
        , Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. i guess your query will give me results for 1 month(correct me if i am wrong) but if its millions of records how do i find out for all the months?

Comment: @jojo do exactly as the query in this answer and you get what you asked for. Maybe you are not getting all the fields you wanted, but you are getting all the fields you asked for.

Comment: @jojo - you are wrong :) Easiest way to find out is to try the query and verify the results.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you a list of names and stock id's where the name purchased 2 or more of the stock ids in the specified month.

```
SELECT Name, StockId
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(ServiceDate) = 2011 AND MONTH(ServiceDate) = 2
GROUP BY Name, StockId
HAVING COUNT(Name)> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
FROM (
select StockID, ProductName, MONTH(serviceDate) as strMonth, year(serviceDate) as strYear COUNT(productName) as ProdCount
FROM testTable

Group By ProductName, StockID, MONTH(serviceDate), year(serviceDate)
)a  where ProdCount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Below query.

```
create table sales 
(ProductName varchar(10),
ServiceDate date,
Name varchar(10),
StockId number(10)
);



insert into sales values('LG',to_date('10-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'John' ,1);
insert into sales values('Sony',to_date('20-02-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Mike' ,2);
insert into sales values('LG',to_date('11-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'John' ,1);
insert into sales values('Samsung',to_date('21-02-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Steve' ,3);
insert into sales values('Toshiba',to_date('02-03-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Kelly' ,4);
insert into sales values('LG',to_date('06-05-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Sean' ,1) ; 
insert into sales values('Sony',to_date('11-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'John' ,1);
```

Query:

```
 select name from sales group by to_char(servicedate,'YYYYMM'),stockid,name having count(*) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as ( 
select distinct date_format(serviceDate, %Y-%m) as month , name, count(product_name)  over 
(partition by name , date_format(serviceDate, %Y-%m) ) as total_orders 
from sales 
) 

select distinct name 
from cte 
where total_orders >=2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already a few answers, including one that's received some validation from the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?